# how to make anchor tag in android clickable

Tags: android, html, anchor

this is my code :

```
TextView aboutL1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.aboutL2);
    aboutL1.setText(Html.fromHtml("This app is open source.<br>The source code is hosted on <a href=\"http://herp.com/derp\">Github</a> "));
    Linkify.addLinks(aboutL1, Linkify.ALL);
```

The word github appears as a link but nothing happens when I click on the link ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to call [setMovementMethod](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setMovementMethod(android.text.method.MovementMethod)):

```
aboutL1.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

(you may not even need to call `Linkify.addLinks` since you used `Html.fromHtml`, but I can't totally remember).