# TextView with different color for one word triggering onclick event

Tags: android, android-activity, onclick, textview

I have message having anchor tag.I want to show the word in anchor tag in different color 
in textview and onclick of that word start different activity.

I have tried textview.settext(Html.fromHtml(message)); it changes color but i also want onclick event on that. Is it posssible to do?

Comment: I dont want textviews onclick event, Inside textview only one word should be clickable that should start other activity.Like anchor tag in HTML

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here :

[how to make anchor tag in android clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502709/how-to-make-anchor-tag-in-android-clickable)

[How do I make links in a TextView clickable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734270/how-do-i-make-links-in-a-textview-clickable)

[How can I make links in fromHTML clickable? (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303160/how-can-i-make-links-in-fromhtml-clickable-android)

**Edit :**

Ummm, well there are multiple ways to do that, you could use a custom url scheme to start the activity. If you need info regarding that, I have written a tutorial on my blog here :

http://myandroidtuts.blogspot.in/2013/07/custom-url-scheme-in-android.html

You could implement a onClickHandler :

```
   textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener{
   public void onClick(View v){
         Intent intent = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
         startActivity(intent);
   }
});
```

Comment: The links are related to webpages. I want same behaviour as anchor tag in html but instead of loading webpage in link i want to start new activity.

Comment: Edited my answer, check now

Comment: The above code is for onclick of textview,but i want onclick of text inside textview.Suppose I have "Hello World" inside Textview,so onclick of only "World" i want to start a new activity not onclick of "Hello World".

Comment: You will have to either break up the text in 2 textviews or use custom url scheme