# Hyperlink in RecyclerView textview

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I am fetching data from JSON and displaying in RecyclerView layout. My textview is displaying whole link. For example, my TextView is install and the link is `http://mydomin.com?id=2054656`. In RecyclerView it should show only `install` text and when it is clicked then is should go to URL. I tried below code.

```
Viewholder.ImageUrlNameView.setText(getDataAdapter1.getImageUrlName());

ImageUrlNameView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(tvAppLink) ;

ImageUrlNameView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

It's working fine but showing whole link instead of text. I hope you understand.

please see my full code after changing textview to button

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
import android.text.util.Linkify;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView;

import java.util.List;

import static android.icu.lang.UCharacter.GraphemeClusterBreak.V;



public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    Context context;

    List<GetDataAdapter> getDataAdapter;

    ImageLoader imageLoader1;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<GetDataAdapter> getDataAdapter, Context context){

        super();
        this.getDataAdapter = getDataAdapter;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_items, parent, false);

        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder Viewholder, int position) {

        GetDataAdapter getDataAdapter1 =  getDataAdapter.get(position);

        imageLoader1 = ServerImageParseAdapter.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();

        imageLoader1.get(getDataAdapter1.getImageServerUrl(),
                ImageLoader.getImageListener(
                        Viewholder.networkImageView,//Server Image
                        R.mipmap.ic_launcher,//Before loading server image the default showing image.
                        android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert //Error image if requested image dose not found on server.
                )
        );

        Viewholder.networkImageView.setImageUrl(getDataAdapter1.getImageServerUrl(), imageLoader1);

        Viewholder.ImageTitleNameView.setText(getDataAdapter1.getImageTitleName());

        Viewholder.ImageUrlNameView.setText(getDataAdapter1.getImageUrlName());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return getDataAdapter.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public NetworkImageView networkImageView ;
        public TextView ImageTitleNameView;
        public Button ImageUrlNameView ;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {

            super(itemView);

            networkImageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.VollyNetworkImageView1) ;
            ImageTitleNameView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_item);
            //ImageUrlNameView = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bAppUrl) ;
            //ImageUrlNameView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
            //Linkify.addLinks(ImageUrlNameView, Linkify.WEB_URLS);

            itemView.findViewById(R.id.bAppUrl).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String url = "ImageUrlNameView";

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });


        }


    }

}
```

getting below error

```
10-27 20:58:43.896 12462-12462/com.android_examples.recyclerviewimagelistview_android_examplescom E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                                                        at com.android_examples.recyclerviewimagelistview_android_examplescom.RecyclerViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter.java:73)
                                                                                                                        at com.android_examples.recyclerviewimagelistview_android_examplescom.RecyclerViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter.java:29)
                                                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5768)
                                                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5801)
                                                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5037)
                                                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4913)
                                                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2029)
                                                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1414)
                                                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1377)
                                                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:578)
                                                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3260)
                                                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3069)
                                                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3518)
                                                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
                                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
                                                                                                                        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1021)
                                                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
                                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
                                                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
                                                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
                                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
                                                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:435)
                                                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
                                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
                                                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
                                                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
                                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
                                                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
                                                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
                                                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
                                                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
                                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
                                                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
                                                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
                                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
                                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1892)
                                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1711)
                                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
                                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
                                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
                                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
                                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
                                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
                                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
                                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
                                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
                                                                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-27 21:03:43.956 12462-12462/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 12462 SIG: 9
```

please check the image what i am trying to get but getting error

[image]

Comment: what is sample output of `getDataAdapter1.getImageUrlName()`? Is it `text `or `URL`. whatever it is will be, it will set to your `ImageUrlNameView` as per your code.

Comment: its url fetch from database. its displaying whole link, i just want to show a text. on click the text it will go to url page

Comment: you should do it like http://stackoverflow.com/a/14517468/3758972. with `HTML`

Comment: If you don't want to show a hyperlink your better off making a button with an onclick that opens the browser.  Just pass it the url

Comment: ok i will try button instead of textview

Comment: i tried button, but startActivity showing error. please see my full code.

Comment: getContext().startActivity(intent);

Comment: still getting same error

Comment: Post the error it could be anything I need to see it

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: ImageUrlNameView gets url. do i need to convert or anything. i have no idea. ImageUrlNameView = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bAppUrl) ; displaying whole url.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126848/discussion-between-asesha-george-and-xjasz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the logic of click into `onBindViewHolder` this way, you have the URL of the current object:

```
 @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder Viewholder, int position) {

            GetDataAdapter getDataAdapter1 =  getDataAdapter.get(position);

            imageLoader1 = ServerImageParseAdapter.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();

            imageLoader1.get(getDataAdapter1.getImageServerUrl(),
                    ImageLoader.getImageListener(
                            Viewholder.networkImageView,//Server Image
                            R.mipmap.ic_launcher,//Before loading server image the default showing image.
                            android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert //Error image if requested image dose not found on server.
                    )
            );

            Viewholder.networkImageView.setImageUrl(getDataAdapter1.getImageServerUrl(), imageLoader1);

            Viewholder.ImageTitleNameView.setText(getDataAdapter1.getImageTitleName());

            Viewholder.ImageUrlNameView.setText("Install");



Viewholder.ImageUrlNameView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        String url = getDataAdapter1.getImageUrlName();

                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {

            return getDataAdapter.size();
        }

        class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

            public NetworkImageView networkImageView ;
            public TextView ImageTitleNameView;
            public Button ImageUrlNameView ;

            public ViewHolder(View itemView) {

                super(itemView);

                networkImageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.VollyNetworkImageView1) ;
                ImageTitleNameView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_item);
                ImageUrlNameView = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bAppUrl) ;
                //ImageUrlNameView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
                //Linkify.addLinks(ImageUrlNameView, Linkify.WEB_URLS);




            }


        }
```

Comment: small correction its context.startActivity(intent);  not my idea. its suggested. working grate. thank you to all

Comment: when i click back button its getting exit from app. how to go back to previous activity. finish(); showing error.

Answer (score 0):

**METHOD 1:** 
Try this which worked for me- 
1)
    String installString = "install";
    String hyperlinkString = "Whatever string " + installString  + " text";
    SpannableString hyperlinkText = makeHyperlinkText(hyperlinkString, installString);
    textView.setText(hyperlinkText);
    textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

2) the function is here :

```
private SpannableString makeHyperlinkText(String hyperlinkString, String textToMakeHyperlink) {
        SpannableString content = new SpannableString(hyperlinkString);
        ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View widget) {
                Intent webviewIntent = new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this, WebviewActivity.class);
                webviewIntent.putExtra("URL", your_url_here); //EDIT
                startActivity(webviewIntent);
                }
            };
            int startIndex = hyperlinkString.indexOf(textToMakeHyperlink);
            int endIndex = startIndex + textToMakeHyperlink.length();
            content.setSpan(clickableSpan, startIndex, endIndex, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            return content;
    }
```

//EDIT: added these files below

3) WebviewActivity class is here -

```
public class WebviewActivity extends AppCompactActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_webview_layout);

        String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("URL");

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        myWebView.loadUrl(url);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

4) Webview Layour class (customize as needed):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.massmutual.css.ui.loan.LoanDisclosureWebView">

    <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**METHOD 2:**
You can change the way you pass the url string. It needs to be HTML format.
Eg:

```
<a href="www.google.com">Click here for google.</a>
```

So i think your text would be something like :

```
    String url = "http://mydomin.com?id=2054656";
    String text = "install";
    String hyperlinkText = "<a href=\"" + url + "\""> + text + "</a>";
```

Let me know if these work for you.

Comment: not working. please see my code i have change textview to button.

Comment: see edits. You can make it work with TextView itself.

Comment: ok see i am getting url from json and set into ImageUrlNameView string. now when i use ImageUrlNameView = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bAppUrl) ; its replacing the text with url. its fine but i dont want to show the url. when i click on install string it should go to the url. you did a grate job. but i cannot change the script , i am not good in android

Comment: and one more thing its RecyclerView. data is in loop